# Help implementing the All Nearest Smaller Values algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_nearest_smaller_values. This is the site of the problem
and here is my code, but I have some trouble to implement it:

```
import java.util.*;
public class stack{

    public static void main(String[]args){

        int x[]=new int[]{  0, 8, 4, 12, 2, 10, 6, 14, 1, 9, 5, 13, 3, 11, 7, 15 };

        Stack<Integer> st=new Stack<Integer>();

        for (int a:x){
            while (!st.empty() && st.pop()>=a){
                System.out.println( st.pop());
                if (st.empty()){
                    break;
                }
                else{
                    st.push(a);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the pseudo code from the site:

```
S = new empty stack data structure
for x in the input sequence:
    while S is nonempty and the top element of S is greater than or equal to x:
        pop S
    if S is empty:
        x has no preceding smaller value
    else:
        the nearest smaller value to x is the top element of S
    push x onto S
```

What is the matter with my code?

Comment: Generally it helps to state exactly what the problem is - are you encountering errors? Is the result wrong, and if so, how? Etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the same pseudo code but I've added brackets so you can see where each statement begins and ends.

```
S = new empty stack data structure
for x in the input sequence:
{
    // peek instead of pop when you're checking what's in the queue
    while S is nonempty and the top element of S is greater than or equal to x:
    {
        pop S // you can call pop here
    }

    if S is empty:  // just check if the queue is empty, don't peek or pop
    {
        x has no preceding smaller value
    }
    else:
    {
        the nearest smaller value to x is the top element of S
    }
    push x onto S
}
```

You had the if/else statement inside the while loop, which was incorrect.

Check the documentation of the stack to understand what `push`, `pop` and `peek` do, here is the documentation: http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html

Answer (score 5):

The method `pop()` doesn't do what you think it does. You should read the [`Stack` documentation](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html#pop()).

Answer (score 1):

In the posted pseudocode the `while` is separate from the `if`/`else`; in your Java code the `if` is inside the `while`.

Also `pop()` *removes* the top element of the stack. You cannot use it to peek at the first element in the condition of `while`.

Answer (score 0):

Will something like this work?

```
int[] inputSequence = new int[] { 0, 8, 4, 12, 2, 10, 6, 14, 1, 9, 5,
                                 13, 3, 11, 7, 15 };
Stack<Integer> S = new Stack<Integer>(); // empty stack data structure
for (int x : inputSequence) {
    while (!S.isEmpty() && topElementOf(S) >= x) {
        S.pop();
    }

    if (S.isEmpty())
        System.out.println(x + " has no preceding smaller value");
    else {
        System.out.println("the nearest smaller value to " + x + " is "
                    + topElementOf(S));
    }
    S.push(x);
}


private Integer topElementOf(Stack<Integer> stack) {
    return stack.peek();
}
```

Comment: @Lirik, I copied the algorithm over and tried to change it to valid Java code. Didn't notice the homework tag - mea culpa.

Comment: Some people directly down-voted you, but I'm just trying to be helpful.

Comment: what's the use of topElementOf? it just calls stack.peek?

Comment: @Lie The loop could be read as _while not S is empty and top element of S greater than or equal to x_ - which is close to how it is presented in the original problem.